# How to disable the default pinch behavior on a web page using Safari?

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari, pinch

**How should I write my own pinch handler method to work with Safari?**

It looks like that Apple no longer lets developers disabling the default pinch facility using below HTML code.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
```

Also, I tried `aTouchEvent.preventDefault();` in my `ontouchstart()` method , which didn't work (default web page pinch still working!)

I need to disable the default pinch on a `div` tag that contains a map in order to write my own method on pinch event to be able to handle zoom in/out through the map.

P.S. I am also aware of disabling pinch is not a good idea and is not recommended or could be law breaking in some countries.